# In react, How to display Modal only one time till logout?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

**How to create following scenario in react ?**

I have created one disclaimer modal which will get open on login. When I close or Agree Disclaimer , it should not be reopen till logout.

Comment: you can use global flag indicating whether modal was opened or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use cookies or localstorage
so when the modal is showen you set this params to true and in logout set to false
and dont show this modal until this param is false or not set and the user is logged in